# GUI for C++ program in visual studio 2005

Tags: user-interface

I am a beginner programmer in C++. I just created a product configurator in C++ now i want to develop a GUI for that in Visual studio 2005. I have never worked in Visual studio before. can someone give some hints that how to start, links for some basic lessons would be a great help.

Comment: Any reason why you are using VS 2005? I mean, VS 2013 can be found fairly easily online...

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio supporting many language for GUI creation like `C#`, `MFC(C++)`, `Visual F#`.
As you said C++ you can go with MFC projects.

You can select/create projects by going into file->new projects->Visual C++->Mfc Application
And for every language you need some guidance.
please follow the below link for more detail.
[msdn link for creating GUI in visual stuudio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235634%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)